# parse a JBoss multipart message in php

Tags: php, web-services, jboss

How it is possible to parse a JBoss response like this with PHP ?

```
------=_Part_58_287452250.1366368388552
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <rootpart@ws.jboss.org>

<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><env:Header></env:Header><env:Body><ns2:retrieveReportResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.lince.it/WSCorporate_1/RetrieveReportService"><report><companyData><companyIdentification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><reportInfo><deliveryDate>2013-04-19T00:00:00+02:00</deliveryDate><reference xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><reportInfo>87080394</reportInfo><deliveryCode>39415434</deliveryCode><originalRequestCode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/></reportInfo><companyEvaluation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><structuralData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><shareholdersData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><financialData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><financialForecast xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><protests xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><closingDown xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><companyName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/></companyData><document><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:document-8b0d480d-7006-4657-87ee-6523e0526b60@ws.jboss.org"/></document></report></ns2:retrieveReportResponse></env:Body></env:Envelope>
------=_Part_58_287452250.1366368388552
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: <document-8b0d480d-7006-4657-87ee-6523e0526b60@ws.jboss.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<BasicAbbrevia><Metadata><Service><Type>CARTESIO</Type><Name>BASIC-ABBREVIA</Name></Service><Document><Id>15033</Id><Line>DOS</Line><Code>CVBA</Code><Name>CARTESIO:BASIC-ABBREVIA</Name><Title>BASIC ABBREVIA</Title><Description>Cerved Group Basic Abbrevia</Description></Document><Subject><IdCervedGroup>5913284</IdCervedGroup><Id>30128510</Id></Subject><Request><Id>87080394</Id><Subject>5913284</Subject><User>WPIT00</User><Time>19/04/2013 00:00:00</Time><Client><Type>WCRV</Type></Client><Output><Target>CERVED</Target><Version>1</Version><Format>XML</Format><Language>I</Language></Output></Request><Response><Stats><ServiceStartTime>19/04/2013 12:46:22.092</ServiceStartTime><ServiceResponseTime>19/04/2013 12:46:26.253</ServiceResponseTime><EnrichmentProcessingElapsed>00:00:01.467</EnrichmentProcessingElapsed><SectionProcessingElapsed>00:00:01.362</SectionProcessingElapsed><TotalElapsed>00:00:04.161</TotalElapsed><Actions count="2"><Action elapsed="00:00:01.346" name="DATI-CAMERALI:DATI-IDENTIFICATIVI" start="19/04/2013 12:46:24.898"/><Action elapsed="00:00:01.321" name="DATI-CAMERALI:CARICHE-E-QUALIFICHE" start="19/04/2013 12:46:24.903"/></Actions></Stats></Response></Metadata><CompanyIdentificationSection><TaxCode>02243110984</TaxCode><REAProvinceCode description="BRESCIA">BS</REAProvinceCode><REANumber>433793</REANumber><CompanyName>QUORUM S.R.L.</CompanyName><RHOAddress><ProvinceCode description="BRESCIA">BS</ProvinceCode><ISTATMunicipalityCode description="BRESCIA">BS029</ISTATMunicipalityCode><City>BRESCIA</City><ToponymCode description="VIALE">VLE</ToponymCode><StreetName>S. EUFEMIA</StreetName><StreetNo>216</StreetNo><PostCode>25135</PostCode></RHOAddress><RHOSlimActivityList><SlimBusinessActivity><Code description="Produzione di software non connesso all'edizione">62.01</Code><Coding>07</Coding></SlimBusinessActivity><SlimBusinessActivity><Code description="REALIZZAZIONE DI SOFTWARE; CONSULENZA SOFTWARE">72.2</Code><Coding>02</Coding></SlimBusinessActivity></RHOSlimActivityList><CertifiedEmail>ADALESISTEMISRL@LEGALMAIL.IT</CertifiedEmail></CompanyIdentificationSection><RepresentativesSection><RepresentativeList><Representative no="3"><TaxCode>02023060391</TaxCode><CompanyEquivalent><REAProvinceCode description="BOLOGNA">BO</REAProvinceCode><REANo>430474</REANo><CompanyName>ADALE SISTEMI S.R.L.</CompanyName><Address><ProvinceCode description="BOLOGNA">BO</ProvinceCode><City>BOLOGNA</City><ToponymCode description="VIA">VIA</ToponymCode><StreetName>CAIROLI</StreetName><StreetNo>8/F</StreetNo><PostCode>40121</PostCode></Address></CompanyEquivalent><OfficesAndAuthorityList><OfficesAndAuthority no="0"><OfficeHeldList><Office no="1"><Code description="SOCIO UNICO">SOU</Code><StartDate><Year>2003</Year><Month>7</Month><Day>29</Day><Value>29/07/2003</Value></StartDate><StartDateType>A</StartDateType></Office></OfficeHeldList></OfficesAndAuthority></OfficesAndAuthorityList></Representative><Representative no="7"><TaxCode>BRNSMN79C03C573X</TaxCode><Individual><LastName>BRANDINELLI</LastName><FirstName>SIMONE</FirstName><Sex>M</Sex><Birth><BirthplaceProvinceCode description="FORLI' - CESENA">FO</BirthplaceProvinceCode><ISTATMunicipalityCode description="CESENA"/><City>CESENA</City><BirthLabelGenere>M</BirthLabelGenere><BirthDate><Year>1979</Year><Month>3</Month><Day>3</Day><Value>03/03/1979</Value></BirthDate></Birth><TaxDomicile><ProvinceCode description="FORLI' - CESENA">FO</ProvinceCode><ISTATMunicipalityCode description="CESENA">FO007</ISTATMunicipalityCode><City>CESENA</City><ToponymCode description="VIA">VIA</ToponymCode><StreetName>C. LUGARESI</StreetName><StreetNo>8</StreetNo><PostCode>47023</PostCode></TaxDomicile><CompanyRepresentative>S</CompanyRepresentative></Individual><OfficesAndAuthorityList><OfficesAndAuthority no="0"><OfficeHeldList><Office no="1"><Code description="AMMINISTRATORE UNICO">AUN</Code><StartDateType>B</StartDateType><AppointmentDeedDate><Year>2012</Year><Month>5</Month><Day>10</Day><Value>10/05/2012</Value></AppointmentDeedDate><DurationCode description="FINO APPROVAZIONE DEL BILANCIO">AB</DurationCode><OfficeAcceptedDate><Year>2012</Year><Month>6</Month><Day>6</Day><Value>06/06/2012</Value></OfficeAcceptedDate><ReferenceDateCompanyReport><Year>2012</Year><Month>12</Month><Day>31</Day><Value>31/12/2012</Value></ReferenceDateCompanyReport><OfficeRegistrationDate><Year>2009</Year><Month>12</Month><Day>17</Day><Value>17/12/2009</Value></OfficeRegistrationDate></Office></OfficeHeldList></OfficesAndAuthority></OfficesAndAuthorityList></Representative></RepresentativeList></RepresentativesSection></BasicAbbrevia>
------=_Part_58_287452250.1366368388552--
```

Comment: SOAP is SOAP, no matter what client/server SW is used for processing. PHP has soap support libraries, just google for it

Comment: Yes, soap is soap and php has an efficient class that supports the common traits. Actually Java JBoss and Microsoft .NET added some functions (as. mime attachments) not implemented in the base php class

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is my handmade solution.

Put the message in the variable `$content` and use this code:

```
preg_match('/\\-+=.*/', $content,$separator);
$separator = trim($separator[0]);
$parts = explode($separator,$content);
array_walk($parts, function(&$part) {
   $part = preg_replace("/.*[\r\n]{2}/ms", '', $part);
   if (trim($part)=='') $part = null;
   if (preg_match("/^[\-]+$/",trim($part))) $part = null;
});
$parts = array_values(array_filter($parts));
```

The `$parts` now is an array with the contents content of the different part of the message.